# Get manifest without downloading the apk

Tags: java, apk, manifest

Is there a way to get the apk's manifest (or just something from it) without downloading the apk?

I need to do it for many apks, and the download time is an issue.
Is there some java package for it?

Comment: APK is a zip archive, so you can't look inside until it is fully downloaded

Comment: Thanks, but I think that is not competently true, as I saw two options:
* TrueZip has something about it, using TPath (see https://truezip.java.net/truezip-path/index.html).

`Path path = new TPath(new URI("http://acme.com/download/everything.tar.gz/README.TXT"));
try (InputStream in = Files.newInputStream(path)) {
    // Read archive entry contents here.
    ...
}`

But I was not able to make it work with reading a file in a zip (only succeed reading the whole zip).

* There is also an option to use InputStream and to download and read just until I get to my wanted file.